# Can I choose different table row items to appear using PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

The while statement of my code fetches three pictures that are bound to a database table and have titles "Wine", "Honey" and "Marmalade". I want it so that when I choose a picture, the action corresponding to the proper if option is executed. Example: If I choose wine "Content" should appear on screen etc.

**view.php**

```
<h4>Choose Product</h4>
<div id="products" class="row" >
<?php
while ($one = $products->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
        <a class="thumbnail" " data-id="<?= $one['id'] ?>">
            <img src="/files/products/<?= $one['id'] ?>.jpg" alt="<?= $one['title'] ?>">

        <?if (@$product['title']='Wine'): ?>
            <p>Content</p>
        <? elseif (@$product['title']='Honey'): ?>
            <p>Other Content</p>
        <? else: ?>
            <p>Default Content</p>
        <? endif; ?>
        </a>
    </div>


<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? _(Are you getting a particular error message?)_

Comment: You want people do php side? I didn't get the question. =\

Comment: It always considers the first if statement, always shows "Content", choosing different pictures doesn't change that although they are bound to different titles. I echoed $one['title'] for every one of them and it shows their titles.